# Macros for section name affects nameref

Tags: macros, pdftex, expansion

I have a LaTeX environment which manipulates a section name through the macro `\sectionname` before eventually creating the section by `\section{\sectionname}}`. The issue is that as this macro is overwritten `\nameref` seems to make use of the macro value when called instead of what the contents of the macro were. I believe this is an issue about expansion, i.e. `\nameref` is trying to literally call `\sectionname` instead of what the literal label for `\section` currently is; but no matter what I try with `\expandafter` or `\edef` placements I don't have a good enough understanding to get it to work.

Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\def\sectionname{First Section}
\section{\sectionname}\label{sec:mysection}


\def\sectionname{Second section}
\section{\sectionname}

I'm trying to cite ``First Section'', but I'm really citing: 
\nameref{sec:mysection}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of MWE]

Comment: One way to do this is to use `\newcommand{\MySection}[1]{\edef\temp{\noexpand\section{#1}}\temp}` and then use `\MySection` instead of `section`.

Comment: @PeterGrill this solution works great! Could you explain a bit more about how it works, I want to understand it in case this happens again in some other case.

Comment: I woud, but feel as if I may not have enough expertize on expansion related issues to properly explain it.

Comment: @PeterGrill sorry but \edef on arbitrary text content is rather dangerous, it should be at least \protected@edef.

Answer (score 2):

`nameref` uses the package gettitlestring to store the title. By default this doesn't expand the text, but you can change that. Be aware that while this gives the content of your command it can also break if the content of a title contains fragile commands, you should then protect them

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{\GetTitleStringSetup{expand}}
\begin{document}

\def\sectionname{First Section}
\section{\sectionname}\label{sec:mysection}


\def\sectionname{Second section}
\section{\sectionname}

I'm trying to cite ``First Section'', but I'm really citing:
\nameref{sec:mysection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! I am concerned about the fragility you mentioned if my document becomes more complex. Does Peter's suggestion above have the same issues if I make the recommended adjustment of \protected@edef?

Comment: imho most things should work as many commands in latex are robust nowadays. And if something breaks you can use `\protect`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a regexp-replace of `\sectionname` by the toplevel-expansion of `\sectionname` does the trick:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__expcmd_itchy_tl
\tl_new:N \l__expcmd_scratchy_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \expandcommand #1 #2 {
  \tl_set:No \l__expcmd_itchy_tl {#1}
  \tl_set:Nn \l__expcmd_scratchy_tl {#2}
  \exp_args:Nnf \use:n {\regex_replace_all:nnN} {
    \exp_args:Nno \use:n 
                  { \exp_args:Nno \use:n {(\c } } 
                  { \cs_to_str:N #1 })+
  }{\u{l__expcmd_itchy_tl}} \l__expcmd_scratchy_tl
  \l__expcmd_scratchy_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\def\sectionname{First Section}
\expandcommand{\sectionname}{\section{bla \sectionname\space bla}}\label{sec:mysection}


\def\sectionname{Second section}
\expandcommand{\sectionname}{\section{blu \sectionname\space blu}}

I'm trying to cite ``bla First Section bla'', and I'm really citing: 
\nameref{sec:mysection}

\end{document}
```

[image]